# Json.net deserializer ignores non-null reference type properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an object with a constructor, which sets all the properties to their default values, including some reference-type values:

```
class MySettings
{
    public int Test1 { get; set; }  // works well
    public MyClass Test2 { get; set; }  // stays at the default value

    public MySettings()
    {
        this.Test1 = 123;
        this.Test2 = new MyClass(1);
    }
}
```

when I try to deserialize an object, the reference-type property (`Test2`) stays at the value, set in the constructor, but the value-type property (`Test1`) deserializes well.

```
_jsonSerializationSettings =
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    };
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MySettings>(jsonString, _jsonSerializationSettings);
```

If I comment setting of `Test2` property in the constructor, it deserializes well too.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per from documentation of [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#ID5RBSection),

`Json.NET` Deserializer use `ObjectCreationHandling.Auto` as default which uses existing object if it has already been created.

If you want to create new object by `Json.NET` itself, you should use `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` in `JsonSerializerSettings` which creates new object irrespective of whether object has already been created or not.

You can set `ObjectCreationHandling` setting in `JsonSerializerSettings` which you can use in your deserializing.

Your setting should be :

```
_jsonSerializationSettings =
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
    };
```

Comment: Thank you!
Json.net have been tried to reuse created `MyClass` object, but all of it's properties are read-only and must be set in a constructor.